# Memcached::getStats not working with Couchbase

Tags: php, memcached, couchbase

I recently set up a server that I'm running Apache, PHP, and Couchbase on. However, I've been having problems testing the Couchbase installation.  In the past, the way I would test that everything is working is with a simple script to run getStats on Couchbase:

```
<?php
  $memcache = new Memcached();
  $memcache->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
  $result = $memcache->getStats();
  print_r($result);
?>
```

This used to return the normal array of statistics.  Lately, though, it doesn't return anything and there aren't any errors being produced in any of my logs.  At the same time, I can still get/set key->values and actually use Couchbase to my hearts content.  Did something change in PHP, the Memcached module, or somewhere else or what am I missing in order to have getStats work again?

I'm running:
- Pecl Memcached 2.0.1
- PHP 5.3.10
- Couchbase 1.8.0

Thanks!

Comment: So you can set cache content and retrieve content but you can`t access statistics via method getStats()?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with moxi.  You may want to kill the moxi process, which will automatically respawn.  If it then starts working then it's probably a moxi issue.  It'd be good to have a [bug report](http://www.couchbase.com/issues/).

Note that you can go around moxi with the [official Couchbase PHP client](http://www.couchbase.com/develop/php/current).  That is designed to be pretty close API wise to PECL memcached.

Full disclosure: I work for Couchbase.

Comment: Lol. Straight from the source!

Comment: Lol, that is one of the things I have liked about using Couchbase/Membase, the devs are super helpful and really fast with replies!  I tried killing the moxi process and after it respawned I tried running getStats() again with no result.  I want to give the Couchbase PHP client a shot before I submit a bug report because it may very well be some issue with PECL Memcached.  When I installed it (PECL Memcached) it threw a very large number of deprecated function warnings during compilation, so now that I have an alternative, I want to try it out.

Comment: Is this problem has been fixed? I am having the same problem.  And I am using php memcached  2.20, libmemcached 1.0.16, Couchbase 3.1.0.  (memcached client received server version is 2.1.1).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know that we ever determined root cause.  I'll reply to your other posting too.