# Memcached getStats returns false with Couchbase

Tags: php, memcached, couchbase

Basically I had the same problem as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625768/memcachedgetstats-not-working-with-couchbase)

And I am using php memcached 2.20, libmemcached 1.0.16, Couchbase 3.1.0. (memcached client received server version is 2.1.1).

I had no problem with setting and retrieving key and value. But getStats just return false when I am connecting to couchbase.

But getStats is works prefectly fine with Memcached server....

Comment: My guess is there is a stat that the php client is tripping over for some reason.  What's your goal with the stats?  Could you update the question?  I may be able to identify a better approach.

Comment: I am using FuelPHP's cache class for accessing Couchbase's memory cache.  The problem with cache class's memcached storage driver validate the memcached connection by using getStats and its fail by getStats returning false.  My current solution is writting a new storage driver to skip that validation.......

Comment: I can't think of much of a better approach there, but it'd be good to fix the issue.  I verified that stats works correctly in the current moxi shipped with memcached.  I can only guess that there may be a bug in the PHP client.

Comment: Yes, I had to comment out that getStats() function in the fuel php code.